# Pulling a SQL Server date to be used in Oracle query within SSIS environment is ignored in the Oracle query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am having trouble in my Oracle query that uses a variable stored in SSIS which has a date that is pulled from *sql server*.

I am using an execute sql task that simply gets a max date from a sql server table and stores it in a variable. E.g.

```
SELECT MAX(t.Date) FROM table t;
```

I then want to use that variable in my Oracle query which is an ADO.NET source connection. I noticed you can't parameterize in those connections and found the work around where you use the sql expression with your user variable in it. So now my Oracle source query looks something like this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM table t WHERE TO_CHAR(t.LastUpdateDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') > " + "'@[User::LastUpdateDate]'"
```

The query syntax itself is fine, but when I run it, it is pulling all rows and seems to be completely ignoring the where clause of the date.

I've tried removing the `TO_CHAR` from LastUpdateDate.
I've tried adding a `TO_CHAR` to my user variable `@[User::LastUpdateDate]`.
I've tried using the `CONVERSION()` function from sql server on `@[User::LastUpdateDate]`.

Nothing seems to work and the query just runs and pulls in all data as if I don't have the `WHERE` clause on the query.

Does anyone know how to rectify this issue or point out what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you for any and all help!

**EDIT:
My date being pulled from SQL Server is in this format: `2022-09-01 20:17:58.0000000`

Comment: You are not using PL/SQL; that is Oracle's procedural language (and is approximately equivalent to T-SQL in SQL Server). You are using SQL in Oracle's dialect/syntax (rather than SQL Server's SQL dialect/syntax).

Comment: @MT0 - Thank you. I will edit my question to remove that part.

Comment: All I can  say is.... this exact same thing happened to me many years ago. However as I recall, I got around it by doing what you did - dynamic SQL. Can I first suggest you try _not_ putting a function around the Oracle field as it makes it non sargeable. Instead put it around the parameter. `WHERE t.LastUpdateDate > TO_DATE('" + @[User::LastUpdateDate] + "','YYYY-MM-DD')"`. However you'll need to align the correct picture format.

Comment: The problem could actually be that `@[User::LastUpdateDate]` is represented by some weird date that actually makes it look like the where clause isn't actually working

Comment: Also, in these cases, to debug, I hard code a date and confirm that that at least works

Comment: If you are going to construct a date literal by concatenating a string that is already in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you might as well aim for something like `date '2022-09-06'` rather than than `to_date('2022-09-06','YYYY-MM-DD')`, even though they mean the same thing.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried removing the TO_CHAR from the oracle field and I get the error: "ORA-01843: not a valid month". The only way that query will work, even directly on the Oracle side, is if I wrap it in the TO_CHAR() function.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I even tried putting a string literal in there and it still is pulling all the dates. I went to the oracle side and ran the original query and the dates are returned in this format `06-JUL-22 08.19.14.000000 PM`. Not sure if that helps or not

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Also, when if I just run the query hard coded as `where TO_CHAR(t.LastUpdateDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') > '2022-08-01'` then it is stored in my sql table as `2022-08-01 20:16:17.0000000`

Comment: What data type is `@[User::LastUpdateDate]`? there is as usual lots of confusion around date data types and formats etc. here. If you can keep everything in date data types, format is irrelevant. However in this case, because you have to concoct a string to get around lack of parameterisation, you have to cross the line and start considering formats.

Comment: Can I also suggest that you use this to monitor what is actually being submitted to Oracle from the Oracle side https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-you-show-sql-executing-on-an-oracle-database

Comment: _I even tried putting a string literal in there and it still is pulling all the dates_ definitely use the Oracle query to see what is being submitted. SSIS can be ambiguous about dynamic expressions. Sometimes it isn't doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just troubleshooting advice

You do not say what data type `@[User::LastUpdateDate]` is, I'll assume it's a datetime

Ideally all datetime data should be kept in datetime data types, then format becomes completely irrelevant. However since it's difficult to parameterise Oracle queries in SSIS, you have to concoct a string to be submitted. Now date format does become important.

On to something a little different, it is a very good habit performancewise, to *not* put functions around columns that you are searching on. This is called sargability - look it up.

Given these things, I suggest that you concoct your required SQL query bit by bit and troubleshoot.

First, format your date parameter as an Oracle date literal. Remember this is normally a bad and unecessary thing. We are only doing it because we have to concoct a SQL string.

So create another SSIS variable called `strLastUpdateDate` and put this hideous expression in it:

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , @[User::LastUpdateDate] ), 2) + '-' +
(DT_STR,3,1252)DATEPART( "mmm" , @[User::LastUpdateDate] ) + '-' +
(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yyyy" , @[User::LastUpdateDate] )
```

Yes this is ludicrously long code but it will turn your date variable into a Oracle string literal. You could simplify this by putting it into your original `max` query but lets not go there. Use whatever debugging technique you have to confirm that it works as expected.

Now you should be able to use this:

```
"SELECT t.*, '"+@[User::LastUpdateDate]+"' As MyStrDate FROM table t WHERE 
t.LastUpdateDate > '" @[User::strLastUpdateDate] + "'"
```

You can try running that and see if it makes any difference. Make sure you use this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-you-show-sql-executing-on-an-oracle-database to monitor what is actually being submitted to Oracle.

This is all from memory and googling - I haven't done SSIS for many years now

I suspect after all this you may still have the same problem because I recall from many years having the same mysterious issue.